# persistent network connection in an android service

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I'm developing a similar app to Telegram or WhatsApp, I need to keep a persistent socket connection to a server (I know this is a resource intensive job and I am sure GCM is not going to help in this case, I can't change the architecture at the moment).

First of all I tried writing a Service but since the service is running in the same process as the app's main thread, whenever the app is closed, then the service is restarted. (I have returned `START_STICKY` on `onStartCommand()`).

After that I am begining to think I would have to develope an independent service and use AIDL to interact with my app.

I'd appreciate if you could help me with this problem.

Comment: "whenever the app is closed, then the service is restarted" -- apps are not "closed" in Android. What do you mean by "closed"?

Comment: in case the user taps on the menu button(the one next to the home button) and slides the app away. also when the device is restarted. I want my app have access to the memory address space in which my persistent socket connection is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can always kill your app if they want to. If you've marked your `Service` as `STICKY`, Android will simply restart it for you. In this case you will need to recognize that your app has been restarted and recreate the persistent socket connection. There is nothing you can do to prevent a user (or Android) from killing your app under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks @David, that's it.